# dataset of stars in the milky way galaxy

Tags: star, planet, exoplanet, milky-way

Does anyone have any idea were I can get a dataset of stars in the milky way galaxy, their mass and their planets and distance of planets from their star?

I have tried various catalogs of NASA. I need something specific. I am planning to run some data analytics on them. So it needs to be in a format I can use preferably excel or data.